# Audio input on schematic

Tags: schematics

I'm not sure in this schematic if the left and right audio inputs are connected by ground, or if the ground of the audio input goes straight to ground.
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a complex circuit without a source from which it's taken, with OP asking about the usage of that circuit without demonstrating sufficient understanding of it. This is analogous to the "questions about the use or repair of electronic devices are off-topic without good understanding design principles" close reasons. We're not here to explain someone else's complex circuits en detail!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just trying to figure out how to wire up the audio input, no harm is meant

Comment: It's a slightly odd symbol for an RCA jack. Both audio grounds (outer rings) are grounded. The audio signals (centre pins) are connected to R6,R7 etc.

Comment: Never mind, it's been a long day haha. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. I'll take the question down. Sorry for the inconvince.

Comment: The common ground symbol means that all instances of it are connected together, and to the power source common (-). This IC is a single package stereo FM transmitter. Don't get confused by the obvious.

Comment: The only problem I see with the question is that there was no question asked. It is not explicitly a repair question, we are not in the business of shutting questions down, but in the business of helping people to write good ones.

Answer (score 2):

According to the schematic both the left and right audio inputs are connected to the ground of your device.

Comment: I thought so as well, but does this make sense? Would that even work in the circuit?

Comment: I hope you mean that the Grounds (outer shell of the RCA connector, if that is what is used) of both inputs are connected to the other Ground points, not that the audio inputs themselves are grounded.